# Basic Qt app doesn't redraw window properly on Debian

Tags: qt, qt4, debian

I've compiled a basic Qt app as given in the Zetcode Qt tutorial:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Simple example");
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

When I run it, the window shows up but Qt doesn't draw in the background. I end up with phantoms from windows behind it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg79s.png

The window will draw the background correctly when I resize it -- MOST of the time. And sometimes there will be a noticeable delay between resizing and drawing in the window.

Am I missing some libraries? Is this a bug? Maybe there's something else I can look up to find a solution?

I'm running sid, my window manager is fluxbox, and my video card is a GeForce FX Go5200 64M.

I should note that this works perfectly well on another computer I have that's running sid as well.

I asked about this on the #qt channel on FreeNode, and one person there seemed to think it was related to the raster painter being used?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a communication problem between fluxbox and Qt.  Could also be a bug / undocumented "feature" of the base `QWidget` implementation.  Try replacing `QWidget` with one of its subclasses, like `QLabel`.

Comment: I doubt that it's a QWidget problem as it works correctly on my other computer. Another user reported that the example worked correctly with their fluxbox.